# Informatica Reg_replace

Tags: regex, quotes, double-quotes, informatica

Here is my Source data :

```
"Hello","World","G"oo"d","Mornin"g""
```

And, my expected target is this way :

```
"Hello","World","G""oo""d","Mornin""g"""
```

Basically, for every quote that comes as part of the real data (excluding the comma and quote that is prefixed and appended after the real data) needs to be replaced with double quotes. How do I achieve this?

I'm thinking a `reg_replace` would suit here. Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: You've take the first step (*reg_replace*) so go a head and show us your code, and say that what's the problem with that.

Comment: I need help with the reg_replace, not sure how to handle this scenario

Comment: You can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: As a might need to use look around for this job http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Can someone please write for me the Regular Expression for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this on an expression, try the following:

```
REPLACESTR(0, your_column, chr(34), chr(34) || chr(34))
```